# Forms with dynamic fields, custom validation and previews

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

I want to use Google Forms and need it to have the followings:

- Dynamic fields: entering data in one field defines next fields with their choices
- Custom validations: validations are more than regex and multiple fields are validated together
- Previews: when entering data, show some live calculations next to the field

Is any of these supported by use of Apps Script, etc. and how?

If these are not supported, do you have any suggestions for a quick way to create such forms preferably using Google toolset?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe any of those features are supported. There might be a work-around for Dynamic fields where you can exploit section branching to emulate it. But that would most likely add a lot of bloat to the form.

Comment: You would need to use an Apps Script Web App and create an input form with HTML.  [Link to Apps Script File - Example Web App Input Form](https://script.google.com/d/125dG42eB9lM4SPq64p0dpR2CBH4ohfHiqu9TvFNM8s4Ra7pt-7kHXoTM/edit?usp=drive_web)